# Crear un instalador en NetBeans con varios instaladores de otros componentes que necesita mi aplicación

Tags: java, netbeans, inno-setup

¿Cómo puedo hacer un solo instalador en NetBeans con varios instaladores de otros programas?

Es decir, cuando instalo mi aplicación necesito instalar 2 programas mas en este caso es el JRE de java y el postgreSQL y me gustaría empaquetarlos en un solo ejecutable, pero no encuentro la manera de hacerlo o desconozco como se hace ya que según he visto se utiliza INNO SETUP COMPILER para hacer un .exe de un .jar sin embargo cuando el programa se intala en otra PC este pide que se instale el JRE de java y lo que necesito es que este JRE se instale de forma silenciosa junto con mi programa.

de antemano muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer que el instalador de tu programa incluya otros instaladores y los ejecute.

Una forma básica de realizar esta tarea, es incluir el ejecutable del instalador como parte de los archivos a instalar y valerte del *evento* [`AfterInstall`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptinstall&anchor=AfterInstall) de dicho archivo, para ejecutarlo.

El ejemplo a continuación ejecutará el procedimiento `InstalarJRE` justo después de *copiar* el ejecutable del instalador en la máquina destino.

Si el instalador falla (devuelve un código de salida distinto de cero) se informará al usuario de la situación.

El procedimiento está escrito en *PascalScript*, que es soportado por inno setup.

```
[Setup]
AppName=Mi Programa
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\Mi Programa

[Files]
Source: "jre-8u281-windows-x64.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; AfterInstall: InstalarJRE
Source: "MiPrograma.jar"; DestDir: "{app}"

[Code]
procedure InstalarJRE;
var
  ResultCode: Integer;
begin
  if not Exec(ExpandConstant('{app}\jre-8u281-windows-x64.exe'), '', ''
    , SW_SHOWNORMAL, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode)
  then
    MsgBox('¡El instalador del JRE falló!' + #13#10 +
      SysErrorMessage(ResultCode), mbError, MB_OK);
end;
```

Dicho esto, un instalador *formal* debiera verificar si sus dependencias están ya instaladas y manejar correctamente las versiones de las mismas, no solamente lanzar su instalador, por lo que debes considerar esto una idea básica.

Otro tema es que muchos instaladores soportan la recepción de parámetros para automatizar su instalación, lo más típico es pasar un parámetro `/silent` para que el instalador se ejecute de manera automática con sus valores por defecto, sin hacer preguntas al usuario. Si quieres hacer esto, debes investigar qué parámetros son soportados por los instaladores que te interesa automatizar y adaptar el código para pasarle dichos valores.

Finalmente, ya que los instaladores como tal no forman parte de tu programa, quizás quieras añadir el *flag* `DeleteAfterInstall`, para que los instaladores no se queden residiendo en el equipo al finalizar el proceso de instalación.

Comment: Gracias esto me ha funcionado muy bien!!